# Jquery toggleClass and CSS animate div width

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to animate the width of a couple of divs next to each other on a mouse click. The clicked div should expand (style of .slide_active) and the other div should shrink (style of .slide_inactive).

```
<body>
  <div class="slide"></div>
  <div class="slide"></div>
</body>
```

I want to use CSS to style the different states of these '.slide' divs

```
.slide {
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: salmon;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

.slide_active {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.slide_inactive {
  width: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

So I'm also using CSS to animate the change, but use Jquery to toggle the different classes.

```
$('.slide').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('slide_active');
  if (!$('.slide').hasClass('slide_active')) {
    $('.slide').toggleClass('slide_inactive');
  };
});
```

It's not working. If only have a limited understanding of code and can't seem to figure this out.

I created a jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/thomascs/go571dw9/1/

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I might have confused you by over simplifying my question. In my application I use 4 divs and 3 possible states, either only .slide or one with .slide_active and all others .slide_inactive. A div can be either 10%, 25% or 70% in width. The .filter got me thinking, but I used the .not instead. Here is the working code: https://jsfiddle.net/thomascs/aj0dvhbm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments! I might have confused you by over simplifying my question. In my application I use 4 divs and 3 possible states, either only .slide or one with .slide_active and all others .slide_inactive. A div can be either 10%, 25% or 70% in width.

The .filter got me thinking, but I used the .not instead.

Here is the working code: jsfiddle.net/thomascs/aj0dvhbm

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this,

```js
$('.parent_slide .slide').on('click', function() {
  $('.parent_slide .slide').addClass('slide_inactive');
  $(this)
  .removeClass('slide_inactive')
  .addClass('slide_active');
});
```

```css
.slide {
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: salmon;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.slide_active {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
.slide_inactive {
  width: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent_slide">
  <div class="slide"></div>
  <div class="slide"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that you're checking if **every** slide has the `slide_inactive` class to then toggle this class on all slides.

Let's change the code a bit:

```
var $slides = $('.slide');

$slides.click(function() {
    $slides
        .filter('.slide_active') // filter out all active slides
        .removeClass('slide_active'); // set slides to unactive

    $(this).addClass('slide_active'); // set target slide to active
});
```

Comment: What about the `.slide_inactive` class?

Comment: Well then you'd add `.addClass('slide_inactive')` after `.removeClass('slide_active')`. But think about it; when a slides has no active class you can assume it's inactive. So why add another class in the first place.

Comment: Because the OPs code seems to have three states, `active`, `inactive` and neither of the two. I agree that it makes more sense to only have 2 states, but that's not what he's showing

Answer (score 0):

Try this, make use of `hasClass() method` to check if `.slide` class consist of `.slide_active` class or not.

```js
$('.slide').click(function() {
 $('.slide').addClass('slide_active');
   $('.slide').removeClass('slide_inactive');
  if($(this).hasClass('slide_active')){
   $(this).addClass('slide_inactive');
    $(this).removeClass('slide_active');
  }
});
```

```css
.slide {
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: salmon;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  transition:width 0.6s ease;
}

.slide_active {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.slide_inactive {
  width: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="slide"></div>
 <div class="slide"></div>
```

Comment: What about the `.slide_inactive` class?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan as OP asked that he is trying to switch between divs, so we could make changes in code and make them to work using add and removeClass.